# Stuck with catpcha solving in python

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, captcha, python-tesseract

We are writing a very simple code for a game which automates an enhancing process (it's our own server so it's just for the fun of it) during this process you occasionally get a captcha which you have to solve in order to continue enhancing. We are stuck up on how we could solve the captchas and this is where we need your help. The code is written in python and is very simple. The captcha is also very simple it's only 3 numbers. (can't be anything else other than numbers from 0-9) Here is how the captcha window looks like: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/27mAK.png]

The code looks like this:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

while True:
  opt = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('asd.png', confidence=.95) #looks for a good enchant
  forgat = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('forgatas.png') #locates the button to press for enhancing
  stop = keyboard.is_pressed("shift") #stops the loop with shift

  if opt: 
          
          print('Done')
          break

  if stop:
          print('Stopped')
          break

  else:
          
          pyautogui.click(forgat)
          time.sleep(0.2)
```

Did some testing with pytesseract:

```
from cv2 import cv2
import pytesseract
import pyautogui

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


img = cv2.imread('ak.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

It successfully converts the img to text but we can't figure out how to copy the text into the text-box in game. Copying the ingame text is not an option.

Would also like to ask you to give suggestions regarding speeding up the process while the locateOnScreen function is still able to keep up (don't want the code to skip over a good enchant for going too fast) and maybe using something else instead of time.sleep because it heavily taxes the system. Sorry if the code is messy we are still very much beginners and we never learned python before. Any help would be greatly appricated! Looking forward to any suggestion!

Comment: is your CAPTCHA color always yellow?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this library I've found some time ago. If you have a set of labelled captchas that service would fit you. Take a look: https://github.com/punkerpunker/captcha_solver

In README there is a section "Train model on external data" that you might be interested in.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)